# solr update/json hangs semi-randomly

Tags: solr

I'm a total solr noob so I'm probably missing important information here.

Solr version: 10.4.2
Platform: Mac OS X

I'm attempting to add about 5000 documents to an empty index. Documents have 4 fields:

- id (string, indexed, stored)
- title (solr.TextField, indexed, not stored)
- keywords (solr.TextField, multi values, indexed, not stored)
- content (solr.TextField, indexed, not stored)

I'm using `update/json` to insert the documents in batches of 100 in a tight loop (making a new HTTP request to the `update/json` endpoint for each batch). The problem gets better if I add, e.g., a 100ms delay between each request. If I delay a full second it goes away completely, but this is obviously unacceptably slow.

I have worked around it by adding very short timeouts for my HTTP requests (1 second), and implementing some retry logic. It works, but of course I get annoying delays all the time as it retries.

My process often hangs waiting for solr to respond at some point during the process. For instance, if I start with a fresh core and test it right now, these are my results for each run in turn:

1. hang on the 45th batch, solr admin shows 3,280 documents
2. hang on the 52nd batch, solr admin shows 3,788 documents
3. hang on the 14th batch, solr admin shows 3,788 documents
4. hang on the 17th batch, solr admin shows 3,788 documents
5. successfully completes all batches, solr admin shows 4,043 documents

The log in solr admin shows no output during any of these runs. At any point after a failed or successful run I can query the index and get back reasonable results considering the data that has been added.

The `update/json` request handler is the one that is "implicitly added" -- it is not specified in my solrconfig.xml.

I have tried switching my locking mechanism from native to simple with no change in behavior.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure where to start.

Additional info:

1: It seems to hang forever. By "hang" I mean Solr never responds to the HTTP request. If I cancel the request and send it again, it generally works fine right away. I have let it wait up to about 10 minutes for a response.

2: My solrconfig.xml has this:

```
<updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
   <updateLog>
      <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
   </updateLog>
   <autoCommit> 
      <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime> 
      <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
   </autoCommit>
   <autoSoftCommit> 
      <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime> 
   </autoSoftCommit>
</updateHandler>
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not describe the actual 'hang'. Is it hanging for a period of time or forever? That makes quite a difference.

I am assuming your actual document (content fields?) are quite large.

There might be a couple of things:

1. Garbage collection. If you allocated a lot of memory to Solr,
   when it hits the limit, the GC could be quite long. There are Java
   flags to enable GC reporting during a test run
2. Index merging.
   Watch the *data/index* directory and see if the files start moving
   around.
3. Look also in the server logs, not just on the WebUI. The
   server logs will have constant chatter about what's going, UI only
   shows the issues.
4. It's also worth checking what your commit and
   soft-commit settings are (in solrconfig.xml).

Comment: I added an update to my question about the hangs and my commit settings (I think...) I'll look for logs on the server and see what I can decipher there. Right now I have it working "fine" by setting a very low timeout for HTTP requests (1 second) and retrying on timeout. This is slow, but it works.